# Checkbox in Jquery UI Dialog doesn't appear in Firefox 22.0 and Opera, but it does in Firefox 20.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, checkbox

i'm having a trouble with some HTML checkboxes

The problem is :
My checkbox in a form that I pop up in a dialog doesn't appear in some version of Firefox and Opera.
I'm actually using Fedora and Firefox 20.0
On Safari the three checkbox doesn't appear. Only the label is show.
Same thing on an other computer on Firefox 22.0

Does someone know a solution ? Or were i can find somme informations about this problem ?
I searched a lot and i didn't find any solution.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="addFormular" title="Create a conference" class="hidden">
    <form id="postform" action="." method="post">
    <div id="checkOption">
        <div class="optionDiv">
            <input class="addBox" type="checkbox" id="checkHD" /><label class="addOption" for="checkHD"><?php echo Lang::getFromKey("HD"); ?></label>
        </div>

        <div class="optionDiv">
            <input class="addBox" type="checkbox" id="checkRecord" /><label class="addOption" for="checkRecord"><?php echo Lang::getFromKey("Record"); ?></label>
        </div>

        <div class="optionDiv">
            <input class="addBox" type="checkbox" id="checkTeacup" /><label class="addOption" for="checkTeacup"><?php echo Lang::getFromKey("Add a tea cup"); ?></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript :

```
var popUpConf = $('#addFormular').dialog({
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            position: {my: "left top", at: "right bottom", of: "window"},
            dialogClass: 'no-close',
            modal: true,
            width: 'auto',
            closeOnEscape: false,
            open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog || ui).hide(); },
            buttons: [

            {   
                text: "Annuler",
                click: function() {

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },

            {
                text: "Valider",
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]
        });

    }
```

And the required CSS :

```
.postForm {
width: 100%;
display: block;
} 

.addOption{
vertical-align: top;
}

.addBox{
margin-top: 1.5px;
}

.optionDiv{
margin-top: 5px
}
```

Thx !

**EDIT :**

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pCw/
This Demo using only my HTML is showing checkboxes on my Firefox 20.0, but it don't show the checkboxes on opera and firefox 22.0... I really can't get it.

Comment: I see checkboxes in your Fiddle in both Opera and FF (latest) under Windows OS. Question is about jQuery UI dialog, but fiddle is raw html snippet. Don't you see checkboxes even in it? Then I'm afraid this is your PC local issue.

Comment: @Tommi : I don't (Firefox 22/Ubuntu) exept if i change the class name `class="addBox"` (but i do not include the CSS) ! So yeah, pretty strange bug.

Comment: Thx for trying to help me ... The only thing we found is that if you change the "addBox" (by "addbox" for exemple) class by any other name, it finaly work on other browser. (I tryied on Opera on a 2nd computer, and on firefox 22.0 on a third computer. And the HTML only, on fiddle didn't work.)

Comment: Exactly, `class="addBox"` seems to be at fault - in combination with Adblock Plus. Once I change the classname, _or_ disable Adblock, they show up.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pCw/6/   its position problem with firefox

Comment: The positionning is not a problem, just a mistakes when i tried to copy and paste my code. I forgot to change it for "window", but it work with my "#createConfButton" ... When the "#createConfButton" exist !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested your fiddle with latest Chrome - same happened, though, I was able to notice the lag in disappearing.

Checking the class - "**addBox**" - that appears to be blocked by **AdBlock** plugins. My Chrome's, AddBlockPlus also caught it and hid it.

Changing the class to something else solved it, you should too.

Comment: Yup, this is the problem, and thx to all of you, i found WHY ! The "addBox" should be never user if you don't want a div to be catch by AddBlock plugins. Now i'll know it :< !

Answer (score 0):

there is problem with position

i check in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pCw/6)

jquery

```
var popUpConf = $('#addFormular').dialog({

    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,

    dialogClass: 'no-close',
    modal: true,
   position:  { my: "left top", at: "right bottom", of: window },
    width: 'auto',

    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog || ui).hide(); },
    buttons: [

    {   
        text: "Annuler",
        click: function() {

            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },

    {
        text: "Valider",
        click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
```

add jquery ui and jquery library.

Comment: The positionning is not a problem, just a mistakes when i tried to copy and paste my code. I forgot to change it for "window", but it work with my "#createConfButton" ... When the "#createConfButton" exist !